# Confusion Matrix Classification Report - Keras

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

I was running a code picked from git to understand how it works. 
Here is my accuracy/loss that I can understand , but I need help to articulate this confusion matrix and the report. Need you help in this.

loss: 0.0553 - acc: 0.9826 - val_loss: 0.0492 - val_acc: 0.9825

Confusion Matrix

```
[[22 10 11  1 15  8  8  8 26 15 14 25  3 33 20]
 [ 9  3  7  3 13  6  2  5  8  6  8  3  0 16 17]
 [11  6  8  0  8  5  1  4  7  9  8  6  1 20 12]
 [ 3  0  2  0  0  2  0  0  2  2  2  2  0  4  2]
 [25  8  3  4 18 10  7  8 11 11 10  7  2 23 11]
 [12  3  4  2  7 13 10  3 15  6  7  3  3 19  9]
 [ 7  5  4  3  5  6  8  4  7  4  7  8  2 19 12]
 [ 6  6  3  0  9  7  7  4  6  8  7  6  2 23  6]
 [18  8  7  2 16  8 10 17 20 25 22 12  3 28 14]
 [17  9 10  3 15  6  7  8 16 15 15 21  0 33 13]
 [15  5  7  3 13 15  8  9 12  8 10 14  2 32 14]
 [17  8  7  0  7  7  6  8 12 15  8  9  3 32 11]
 [ 2  2  1  0  1  1  5  0  4  4  4  3  0  1  1]
 [38 22 26  2 20 15 19 13 41 34 24 20  7 50 23]
 [14  9  9  0 11 11  9  7 18 20 16 14  1 22 14]]
```

below is the classification report.

```
Classification Report
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

     A       0.10      0.10      0.10       219
     B       0.03      0.03      0.03       106
     C       0.07      0.08      0.07       106
     D       0.00      0.00      0.00        21
     E       0.11      0.11      0.11       158
     F       0.11      0.11      0.11       116
     G       0.07      0.08      0.08       101
     H       0.04      0.04      0.04       100
     I       0.10      0.10      0.10       210
     J       0.08      0.08      0.08       188
     K       0.06      0.06      0.06       167
     L       0.06      0.06      0.06       150
     M       0.00      0.00      0.00        29
     N       0.14      0.14      0.14       354
     O       0.08      0.08      0.08       175


   micro avg       0.09      0.09      0.09      2200
   macro avg       0.07      0.07      0.07      2200
weighted avg       0.09      0.09      0.09      2200
```

Please help me to understand the classification report. I read theory for confusion matrix but unable to articulate this keras output.  Also, what is micro avg,mcro avg etc .Need help to understand . Is the above accuracy seems fine. Please pardon me, I am very new to this.

Comment: Could you provide the code you used? Also I think it's not a coding problem but a statistic problem, you might want to moove your question to stat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are struggeling with micro avg the most. 
Precision, recall and f1 are very basic and you will find a clean explanation [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/accuracy-precision-recall-or-f1-331fb37c5cb9):

For Micro Avg you can find a good example [here](http://rushdishams.blogspot.com/2011/08/micro-and-macro-average-of-precision.html):
But basically it is just an different way to calculate the average.

> Micro- and macro-averages (for whatever metric) will compute slightly
>   different things, and thus their interpretation differs. A
>   macro-average will compute the metric independently for each class and
>   then take the average (hence treating all classes equally), whereas a
>   micro-average will aggregate the contributions of all classes to
>   compute the average metric. In a multi-class classification setup,
>   micro-average is preferable if you suspect there might be class
>   imbalance (i.e you may have many more examples of one class than of
>   other classes).

[Cited from here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin)

Comment: Than you ! Is above classification report seems having good accuracy? I will definitely read the link you provided.

Comment: Well it depends on your data, but in general no, it seems like there is something wrong with it. Because your accuracy is quite good, but your individual scores for each class is pretty bad. Could be a very unbalanced data set. You can take the f1 score as a overall balanced metric, it should be much higher.

Comment: Yes, data is unbalanced. I am not sure now if I can go with this model .

Comment: Well, depends on what you want to achieve. How big is your data set?
You can use class_weights for balancing

Comment: 19k train and 2.2k val

Comment: [Look here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras) 
And pls accept the answer, if it answers the initial question, thx

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I”ll go through it.