# Automatic weight assignment - Unbalanced data in Keras and Confusion Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have 10 classes to classifiy using CNN . Data is unbalanced in all those 10 classes , for that I tried both of the below mentioned techniques but the F1 score is not showing any improvement. 
You can refer to [Confusion Matrix Classification Report - Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958824/confusion-matrix-classification-report-keras)  This is the confusion matrix I got initially without using the below code . But after using the below code also, the F1 score hardly improved. However the validation accuracy was 98%+. Need your help on this.

```
#Method 1
counter  = Counter(training_set.classes)
max_val = float(max(counter.values()))
class_weights  = {class_id:max_val/num_images for class_id,num_images in counter.items()}

#Method 2
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import numpy as np

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
               'balanced',
                np.unique(training_set.classes),
                training_set.classes)
```

Comment: You need our help on *what exactly*? What is your exact issue?

Comment: Val Accuracy is 98%+ but F1 score is less . Want to improve F1 score. Thats why I tried both of the above mentioned methods to assign weights to classes automatically but that didnot helped. So need help to increase f1 as I know it is coming because data is highly unbalanced in all 10 classes.

Comment: You cannot say that F1-score is "less" than the accuracy, because it is like comparing apples to oranges. And asking here just how you can improve your F1-score, without us knowing anything about your data, is way too broad IMHO...

Comment: Ok ! So what I know that only test and val accuracy is not a parameter to know how well you model will perform . There should be good F1 score attached with it in case of image classification problem . Thats why I do not think there is any case of apple or orange comparison . Its standard process to find how accurate your model is built. Your suggestion on this ?